# how to get column names for the particular table using sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I am facing an issue when fetching column names for the particular table

I wrote the following query

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM all_tab_cols 
WHERE  Table_name like 'tabelname';
```

But what happen in table have 54 columns but when I run that code 224 columns coming. I don't known why.

Comment: Is this SQL Server or Oracle?  I'm assuming Oracle from your code?

Comment: yes oracle we are using

Comment: As an aside, the `LIKE` that way has not much sense. If you use the `LIKE`, you probably need some `%`, otherwise you should better use the `=`

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Oracle, not SQL Server.

`all_tabl_cols` shows columns from all tables the current user has *access* to, not those owned by the current user. If the same table exists in different schema, all of them will be shown.

The `LIKE` operator makes no sense if you don't use a wildcard pattern with it. It would be cleaner to use `Table_name =  'tabelname'` instead.

Oracle stores table names in UPPERCASE (unless you created them using those dreaded double quotes). And string comparison is case-sensitive in Oracle. So you must compare the the content of the column `table_name` with an uppercase name-

You can either use `user_tab_cols` instead of `all_tab_cols`

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM user_tab_cols 
WHERE table_name = 'THE_TABLE';
```

or you need to specify the owner:

```
SELECT column_name 
FROM all_tab_cols 
WHERE table_name = 'THE_TABLE'
  AND owner = user;
```

Comment: i tested above both queries it's not coming... empty showing in column_name column

Comment: @VKChikkadamalla: that's impossible - you can't create table with empty column names. **edit your question** and add the `create table` statement for the table in question. Also: Oracle stores table names in UPPERCASE and string comparison is case-sensitive.

Comment: done .... 
SELECT column_name
FROM   all_tab_cols
WHERE  table_name = 'VERIFICATION'
AND owner = 'APPDB'
      AND column_name NOT IN ( 'password', 'version', 'id' )

Answer (score 0):

SELECT column_name
FROM   all_tab_cols
WHERE  table_name = 'VERIFICATION'
AND owner = 'APPDB'
      AND column_name NOT IN ( 'password', 'version', 'id' )

Comment: this is an answer for my issue